# "uagb/section and uagb/columns block"

Tags: plugins, html, block-editor

When I go to edit my "page", it takes me to a page that says "Your site doesn’t include support for the "uagb/section" block. You can leave this block intact, convert its content to a Custom HTML block, or remove it entirely."

I believe it has to do that this is a Gutenberg page and not Elementor? But when I click "edit with elementor" it completely changes the template and makes it unusable.

I have tried deleting and redownloading the page template, tried using a different page template and have tried using elementor. Nothing works! Anyone know what the deal is?

Answer (score 1):

UAGB refers to [Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-addons-for-gutenberg/), a plugin that creates custom blocks for Gutenberg, the block-editor.

If you wish to use the uagb/section block (which uses both Gutenberg and UAGB), you'll need to install and activate the `Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg` plugin.
If you already have that plugin installed and activated and the error still appears, the error is specifically with that plugin and their staff would be able to best assist you :)